# delete numbers from a column

Tags: vba, formula

I have  the following mumbers in column  B

```
4025015659
4025015660
4025015661
4025015662
-266490.78
-266491.78
-266492.78
-266493.78
0
0
0
```

I need to  the  delete the all numbers except negative numbers. Is it possible to have a formula  or  vba code to do so.

Comment: Do you need the cells gone (so the negative numbers start at row 1), or just empty?

Comment: Is there actually one or more zeroes and can the data be sorted?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
Sub deleteRows()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.CountLarge).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "B") < 0 Then
             Cells(i, "B").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: instead of  deleting the row ,can we  clear  the  cells  in which  the numbers are

Comment: Use `Cells(i, "B").Clear` instead of `Cells(i, "B").EntireRow.Delete` to clear cells

Answer (score 1):

It is more efficient to delete in one go and use a With statement/qualify your range

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub deleteRows()
    Dim unionRng As Range, loopRange As Range, rng As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet3") '>==Change to correct sheet
        Set loopRange = .Range("B1:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        For Each rng In loopRange
            If rng.Value < 0 Then
                If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, rng)
                Else
                    Set unionRng = rng
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then unionRng.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```